# Mysql join where specific record in one table not in other

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've looked at other examples of "data from one table not in other" SQL but still can't figure this out.

Table "pictures" contains:

- "id", an auto increment ID number for this picture
- "owner", an ID number referring to a unique user

Table "ratings" contains:

- "picture", a reference to an entry in the "pictures" table
- "userby", an ID number referring to a unique user

I want to select all pictures which have no entry in the ratings table *by a specific user* AND where the picture owner is not that user.

For example I might want to select all pictures which user 5 has not rated and is not the owner of.

Usually this would be a join between pictures and ratings and check if the ratings record is null, but I can't seem to get the addition of doing it only for specific users right.

How can I do this? I want to avoid sub-selects if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the additional checks to the join predicate and not in the where clause.

So something like

```
SELECT *
FROM pictures p LEFT JOIN
ratings r ON p.ID = r.PictureID AND r.UserID = 5 
WHERE r.ID IS NULL
AND p.OwnerID <> 5
```

Have a look e this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aabc/3)

Comment: Thank you very much. In your example above you've put r.UserID in the ON and p.OwnerID in the WHERE. Can you explain why they're in those positions?

Comment: The r.UserID needs to be part of the `JOIN` predicates to ensure that you correctly filter the `LEFT JOIN`, whereas the p.OwnerID should be in the `WHERE` clause to correctly filter the `Pictures` returned.

Comment: Great, thank you. I didn't really get the difference between filtering the join vs the results before, which stumped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from pictures as p
where p.owner <> 5
  and not exists(select * from ratings where picture = p.id and userby = 5)
```

1. first select pictures which is not owned by user  `p.owner <> 5`
2. then search ratings for that picture by user `exists(subquery)`
3. use not if need picture for which no rating shoul exists

Unfortunately result you need could not be produced by 1 step combination (without subselect), because to do so an operation required, that can combine something existent (any picture not owned by user ) with something nonexistent ( missing rating by user ).

If there were some table containing fact that user did not rate some picture, then it would be possible! SQL can operate with things that exists only. That is what not `exists(subquery)` do - it realizes fact that there are no ratings given by user to a picture.

Comment: Thank you, this should work but I was looking for something without a subselect.